# equation tangent line. $f_a(x)=(x-a)e^{a+2-x}.$

Tags: derivatives

Let $f$ be the following function $$f_a(x)=(x-a)e^{a+2-x}.$$ I have to determine a point where the tangent in this point meet $Oy$ axis in point $A(0,2012)$.

I made $f'(x)=(1-x+a)e^{a+2-x}$. and then equation of tangent:

$y=f(b)+f'(b)(x-b)$
$$y=(b-a)e^{a+2-b}+(1-b+a)e^{a+2-b}(x-b)$$. now I make $y=2012$ and $x=0$ but i don't know how to find $b$.

thanks :)

Comment: Does the point lie on the curve?

Comment: Can you post the original question?

Comment: of  course!!! I must find the point in which the tangent at this point meet $Oy$ in $A(0,2012)$

Comment: @luli: Ok. That was my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the point is $(x_0,y_0)$, then it satisfies the curve equation

> $$ y_0 = (x_0-a)e^{2-a+x_0} $$

and tangent equation

> $$ y_{{0}}-2012=-{{\rm e}^{a+2-x_{{0}}}} \left( -1+x_{{0}}-a \right) x_{{0
> }}
> . $$

Now, you need to solve the two equations. By the way, it is not easy to solve this system. So, are you sure of your function?

Comment: yes, I'm sure! :)